# Oracle Running Total

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

Looking for advice with 2 different types of sub-totals using PLSQL.

I need to pull a data set with 1) a unique headcount, and 2) a total number of credits, as a running total over time.

Raw Data:
This is the transactional data -- every time a student registers or a course, a record is inserted with the date, student id, and credits (along with course number and a bunch of other relevant data).  One record per course per student.

```
STUDENT_ID   CREDITS   DATE
1            3         01-JAN-12
1            2         02-JAN-12
57           1         03-JAN-12
1            1         03-JAN-12
```

Processed Data:
This is what the boss needs to see -- it will be used for trending later (to see, for example, how this year's Jan-01 is measuring up against last year's Jan-01, etc.).

```
UniqueHeadcount   SumCredits   Date
1                 3            01-JAN-12
1                 5            02-JAN-12
2                 7            03-JAN-12
```

The brute approach to this is to write a bunch of separate SELECTS (one for each day), and UNION them together.  For example:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT STUDENT_ID) as "UniqueHeadcount",
  SUM(CREDIT_HR) as "SumCredits",
  '01-JAN-12' as "DATE"
FROM
  REGISTRATIONS
WHERE
  TO_CHAR(DATE,'yyyymmdd') <= '20120101' 
GROUP BY
  '01-JAN-12'

UNION

SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT STUDENT_ID) as "UniqueHeadcount",
  SUM(CREDIT_HR) as "SumCredits",
  '02-JAN-12' as "DATE"
FROM
  REGISTRATIONS
WHERE
  TO_CHAR(DATE,'yyyymmdd') <= '20120102' 
GROUP BY
  '02-JAN-12'

UNION

...
```

And that works -- the results are accurate -- but as you can see -- this is nowhere near elegant -- and if you have to do it for 365 days, well...it's a beast.  There's got to be a better way to do it.

So far in my search, I've learned about an 'OVER' clause that I can use -- like this:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT STUDENT_ID) OVER(ORDER BY TRUNC(RSTS_DATE) ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) "UniqueHeadcount",
  SUM(CREDIT_HR) OVER(ORDER BY TRUNC(RSTS_DATE) ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as "SumCredits",
  TRUNC(RSTS_DATE) as "DATE"
FROM
  REGISTRATIONS
```

This query is way, way shorter (yay) -- but has two significant problems that I can't yet find my way around.  First is that it doesn't work (by design, aparently?) with the COUNT DISTINCT.  So I comment that out for a moment, but then run into the second problem: it ignores the TRUNC() function.  The RSTS_DATE, though it appears to be just a day/month/year value when you run a SELECT on it, actually holds the time as well, so the result set I get is not summed simply over date, but also over times -- so instead of one record per day, my processed data returns hundreds of records per day (one for each individual course registration).  For example:

```
UniqueHeadcount   SumCredits   Date
1                 3            01-JAN-12
1                 5            02-JAN-12
2                 6            03-JAN-12 (hidden time: 07:32:27)
2                 7            03-JAN-12 (hidden time: 08:01:33)
```

Not what I'm after.

So I'm looking for expertise -- if what I've explained so far makes sense -- is there another way to use the OVER clause, or perhaps there may be another feature of PLSQL altogether I should be using for this?  I'm not strong in PLSQL if you can't tell, but if anyone can give me some direction -- even just words to google, I'd appreciate the help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WITH CRdata AS
(
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT STUDENT_ID) AS UniqueHeadcount,
    SUM(CREDIT_HR)                     AS SumCredits,
    TRUNC(RSTS_DATE) RSTS_DATE
     FROM REGISTRATIONS
    GROUP BY TRUNC(RSTS_DATE)
)
 SELECT SUM(UniqueHeadcount) OVER(ORDER BY RSTS_DATE ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS UniqueHeadcount,
  SUM(SumCredits) OVER(ORDER BY RSTS_DATE ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS  SumCredits, 
  RSTS_DATE 
  FROM CRdata
```

Comment: Thanks -- the problem with that is, it only counts & sums for each individual date.  What I need it to do is count & sum for every record leading up to that date (i.e., a running total, as opposed to a daily total).  Does that make sense?

Comment: Getting closer.  That works great for the running total of credits (which is more progress than I had been able to make), but still returns just a daily total for unique headcount.  I'm going to play around with that a bit though to see if I can modify it somehow.

Comment: @tamago Updated the answer. Pls check. Here is SqlFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c694d/4

Comment: -1 You can't sum up two count(distinct X) and assume the sum of the two is still a count(distinct). Because of intersections of sets of X, your sum not longer a count(distinct).